# AAC and M4A audio formats don't work on Android building with Corona

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I use Corona SDK.

I tried different audio formats on cell phone Galaxy 2S with Android 2.3.5 on it. Only MP3 files work ok , AAC and M4A files don't work.

According to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
the M4A audio files have to work ok on Android 2.3.5

What do I miss?

COMMENT: Did anybody tried it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.gorgonloop.MediaFix
?

Comment: try changing the bit rate.  128 kbps works normally!

Comment: I tried to set this bit rate to m4a audio file, with frequency = 11025 Hz ,it didn't help.

Comment: I have no idea then! Try posting in Ansca forums. http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Its often a mimetype problem. Use this:

```
Intent tostart = new Intent();
                tostart.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap
                        .getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file)
                                .toString());
                String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
```

Comment: I write code in Lua language, I think that there is no any way to add Java code.

Comment: Mimetypes:
.mp3 -> "audio/mpeg"
.ts -> "text/texmacs"
.3gp -> "video/3gpp"
.m4a -> "audio/mpeg"

look to it that your file endings are lower case - could be a problem if not (but dont know exactly).